# Volume dialogue is not disappearing from screen in Samsung mobile

Tags: samsung-mobile

In my mobile volume dialogue appeared across the middle of the mobile screen. it can be clicked to activate/deactivate it but can't remove it. It so affecting using his phone. Tried to shut down the phone but the dialogue is across the shutdown button.

Answer (score 0):

All we need to restart the mobile somehow. So, try holding the power button and volume down button together for about 10 seconds to hard restart it. After restarting, that dialogue will disappear.